# Position of a Dialog relative to a View in Android

Tags: android, dialog, position

I have an `ImageView` inside a `ConstraintLayout` in my Activity. I want to show a custom `Dialog` (with a custom layout) right on top of this ImageView whenever I click on it.

I have achieved this on my device by tweaking the `LayoutParams` "x" and "y", but, of course, it fails when I test it on a device with another density (as it also would on a different screen size, I guess). The position is wrong.

How can I make sure my dialog always shows up right above and centered on this ImageView? I'm having a hard time figuring out positions and sizes of views in Android.

```
priority.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showCustomDialog();
            }
        });


private void showCustomDialog() {
        dialog = new MyDialog(MainActivity.this);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams param = window.getAttributes();

        //any ideas?

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Why using a dialog? You could achive the same with a custom view or a fragment, positioning dialogs it's not easy in my expirience

Comment: @Gonzalo Beginner here. How could I achieve that with a fragment? It'd have to be the same size of the ImageView it would substitute? Or is there a way to make it 'float' above the layout?

Comment: If I'm right, ``ConstraintLayout`` let you set views over another views. So you can show/hide or create/destroy a view/fragment when clicking the image. You could also add a background to your over layout to show a fade like dialogs.

Comment: @Gonzalo I was thinking about placing a viewgroup on top of that ImageView and changing its visibility. Didn't know I could animate that transistion, though.